# Can I have const parameter packs?

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, variadic-templates

Alright so

Working on a simple logging system for the fun of it, came across an interesting issue. I thought it would be nice to be able to write something along the lines of:

`Log(Info, "Result: {}", value);`

To give me a result like

`Result: 45`

(Using fmt's formatting style here.)

So I set up the function like so:

```
template <typename ...args_t>
void Log(LogLevel Level, const char* Message, args_t&&... Args)
```

Works great, no problems there. However, I'm of the mindset that if an argument isn't modified by the function, it should be marked as const (for optimization and as a note to the programmer), so I tried this:

```
template <typename ...args_t>
void Log(const LogLevel Level, const char* Message, const args_t&&... Args)
```

This keeps giving me errors, VS2017 gives me

`error C2665: 'Log': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types`

Am I just doing this wrong? Should I not worry about parameter pack const-ness? Is there a better way to do this? This parameter packing business is difficult to wrap my head around sometimes.

(I spent about 3 hours looking into this and couldn't find any relevant information on stack overflow or the internet at large, please forgive me if this has already been answered somewhere else.)

Comment: suggestion: look for "perfect forwarding" and "universal references"

Comment: anyway: try with `const args_t & ... Args` (only one `&`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a forwarding reference, when what you really want is a const reference.

Replace `args_t&&` with `const args_t&`.

A forwarding reference is declared using the same syntax as an rvalue reference, with a double `&` (so `&&`).  What distinguishes one from the other is whether or not it appears in a *deduced context*: forwarding references are deduced, rvalue references are not.  In other words, if the compiler uses your function arguments to figure out what the template parameters are (such as in your case), it's a forwarding reference.  Otherwise, it's an rvalue reference.

In your case, a `const` reference is preferable because you explicitly intend to not modify the arguments.  Since you will never want to accept parameters by non-`const` reference, you don't need perfect forward, using a `const` reference will get you the compiler-checked immutability as well as the ability to accept prvalues (such as literals, etc).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Do `const` references normally allow prvalues? That's something I've always had trouble with for some reason.

Comment: @Nemo Yes, any value category (glvalue, xvalue, or prvalue), either const or non-const, can bind to a const reference, which is great, as long as you don’t need to modify the reffered-to object.

Comment: You, my friend, are excellent. Thank you for the clarification.